# volume mongodb with docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, docker-volume

I try to turn docker-compose with volume mongodb; But Iget this error and I don't know the origin of this error any idea:

```
ERROR: for api_db_1  Cannot start service db: OCI runtime create failed: invalid mount {Destination:mongo-data Type:bind Source:/var/lib/docker/volumes/110cc05fb16f8f6381dea1ff6d17e95e4f8458d98e87e9524514653b19db8e6d/_data Options:[rbind]}: mount destination mongo-data not absolute: unknown
```

I use image mongo:3.6-xenial for mongo and docker-compose version 1.29.2.

Comment: Can you share your `docker-compose` file?

Comment: mount point mapping should be like 
volumes: 
        - /path/on/the/host:/data

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the same error.
My problem was that I didn't specify the file path in which the volume was set in.

I believe for your case, you have a service called `db` that uses volumes called `mongo-data`.
Something like below...

```
services: 
  db:
    // other service specifications
    volumes:
      - mongo-data
```

What I did to solve was to specify the file path docker can look for, similar to this...

```
services: 
  db:
    // other service specifications
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:mongo-data-file-path
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm with the same error here :-(

```
ERROR: for firebird_db_1  Cannot start service db: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: invalid mount {Destination:storage Type:bind Source:/var/lib/docker/volumes/7d63ff4c2624358a5278b14e08e911077dae3359709bd5e114b25591dbf6e1a0/_data Options:[rbind]}: mount destination storage not absolute: unknown
```

my docker-compose file is this:

*PS.: this docker-compose file was working until a few weeks ago...*

```
version: "3.2"
services:

  db:
    image: jacobalberty/firebird
    volumes:
      - ./storage
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      TZ: America/Sao_Paulo
      ISC_PASSWORD: masterkey
      FIREBIRD_DATABASE: dev
      FIREBIRD_USER: dev
      FIREBIRD_PASSWORD: dev
      EnableLegacyClientAuth: 'true'
    ports:
      - 3050:3050
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an absolute path for volume **mongo-data** in `docker-compose` file should work.